# Problem by execution of maven Assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven multi-module projects. Child-Project A should be packaged as a WAR and a fat JAR.

To achieve this, I  defined in the POM of A :

```
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

and I used the assembly plugin, which I bound to the package phase :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

With the command line, when i go to project A and run

```
mvn clean package
```

everything works fine. But when i use the maven menu in IntelliJ and pass the same command, some classes are missing in the generated JAR. I can't understand why the same command produces different results. Can someone helps me understand this?

Comment: Using different environments could produce different results. Why do you need to run it via IDEA IntelliJ ? Not using a CI ?

Comment: We're working on setting up a CI. It's a goal but we're not there yet. Meanwhile, i would find it very convenient to can produce a JAR directly from IntelliJ.